# How do you not touch the ground for 18 seconds?

Tags: achievements, unepic

This challenge exists in the game Unepic:

> [image: WET FLOOR, WATCH YOUR STEP: Do not touch the ground or ladders for 18 seconds.]

Is there any item or so that makes this possible? Double jumping or air control do not really exist in the game, so I do not see how to achieve this.

Comment: I tried jumping from zip wire to zip wire all the way down the mine, did it perfectly twice with 17.9 seconds, never again, it's the single most frustrating thing I've ever done, to absolutely no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to do it in the mine. at the very top, stand on the platforme. when it start to decend, jump to the left under the little ledge. Do the zip line all the way down and at the end jump just before touching the last ledge. you will fall at the bottom and it should be done. it work for me.